# Object Detection: Aspect Ratio and Scale of Anchor Boxes

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision, object-detection-api, faster-rcnn

I am working on an object detection problem on my own dataset. I want to figure out the scale and aspect ratio that I should specify in the config file of Faster RCNN provided by Tensorflow object detection api. The first step is image resizer. I am using Fixed shape resizer as it allows batch size of more than 1. I read that this uses bilinear interpolation for downsample and upsample. How to calculate the new ground truth box coordinate after this resizing. Also, once we have the new ground truth box coordinates, how do we calculate the scale and aspect ratio of anchor boxes that can be specified in the config file to improve the localisation loss.